# Expression of type Any doesn't conform to expected type_$1

Tags: scala

I have problems with undestanding Scala's type system.

```
class A[T](var value: T)
class B[T](val a: A[T], var newValue: T)

val list = new MutableList[B[_]]()
val a: A[Int] = new A(10)
val b: B[Int] = new B(a, 11)
list += b

val someB = list.head
someB.a.value = someB.newValue
```

And after compile i see the error:

```
Error:(12, 24) type mismatch;
found   : A$A36.this.someB.newValue.type (with underlying type _$1)
required: _$1
someB.a.value = someB.newValue
                      ^
```

Both `someB.a.value` and `someB.newValue` have the same type but Scala's compiler actually doesn't think so. How this error can be fixed ?

Comment: Type of `list.head` is `B[_]`, i.e. internal type is not preserved: `case class C[T](v: T); List[C[_]](C(1), C("123")) //=>  List[C[_]] = List(C(1), C(123))`, so if your code compiles you will be able to assign integer to a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't expect the compiler to figure out two existentials are the same, even if they clearly have to be. Workarounds:

1. Use a type variable pattern:

   ```
   list.head match {
     case someB: B[a] => someB.a.value = someB.newValue
   }
   ```
2. Extract a method:

   ```
   def setValue[A](b: B[A]) = b.a.value = b.newValue
   setValue(someB)
   ```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution does its job.

Answer (score 0):

One of solutions I have found is to eliminate usage of existential type with abstract types.

```
class A[T](var value: T)
abstract class B {
  type T
  val a: A[T]
  val newValue: T
}

val list = new mutable.MutableList[B]()
val aa = new A(10)
val b = new B {
  type T = Int
  val a = aa
  val newValue = 11
}
list += b

val someB = list.head
someB.a.value = someB.newValue
```